# Elastic Beanstalk 500 Error: Cannot find settings

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

I am trying to deploy my django app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. After deploying, I am getting a 500 Internal Error when opening the url. The logs state "ImportError: No module named settings.production". I understand that this means that the server cannot find my settings file, but it works fine on my local. I feel I am missing something very obvious.

With some stuff omitted...

Here is my .ebextensions 02_python.config:

```
option_settings:
    "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
        DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "config.settings.production"
        PYTHONPATH: "/opt/python/current/app/johngoben:$PYTHONPATH"
        "ALLOWED_HOSTS": ".elasticbeanstalk.com"
    "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
        WSGIPath: site/config/wsgi.py
        NumProcesses: 3
        NumThreads: 20
    "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles":
        "/static/": "www/static/"
```

Here is my wsgi config:

```
import os

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings.production")
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "settings.production"

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

And here is my app structure

```
project-root/
    .ebextensions/
        01_packages.config
        02_python.config
    .elasticbeanstalk/
        config
    project/
        config/
            wsgi.py
            settings/
                __init__.py
                local.py
                production.py
                base.py
         app1/
         app2/
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing

```
option_settings:
    "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
        DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "config.settings.production"
        PYTHONPATH: "/opt/python/current/app/johngoben:$PYTHONPATH"
        "ALLOWED_HOSTS": ".elasticbeanstalk.com"
    "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
        WSGIPath: site/config/wsgi.py
        NumProcesses: 3
        NumThreads: 20
    "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles":
        "/static/": "www/static/"
```

to

```
option_settings:
    "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
        DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "project.config.settings.production"
        PYTHONPATH: "/opt/python/current/app/johngoben:$PYTHONPATH"
        "ALLOWED_HOSTS": ".elasticbeanstalk.com"
    "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
        WSGIPath: site/config/wsgi.py
        NumProcesses: 3
        NumThreads: 20
    "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles":
        "/static/": "www/static/"
```